# Rsync running every month can't stop it

Tags: rsync, backup, locate

I have never used rsync for backup before. I'm not a advanced user by any means, but enjoying Linux. I was following instructions, from a website (have now lost the url) and I managed to set up rsync to run once a month. Of course, being a newbie with rsync I had it back up the entire root directory, which as you know, is "way" too much. I thought I had killed it, but each month (or 30 days) it fires off, filling up my drive. I have searched and searched, and can't find from where, or what is launching rsync.

I was using cli when I started it. It seems like it might have mentioned it set up a daemon or process to run it like a cron. I have run crontab -e and found it there, and removed it. It still runs, so apparently I also set up something to run it another way as well.

Can you tell me how to find where it is running so I can stop it?
Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon
Cinnamon Version 4.6.7
Linux Kernel 5.4.0-47-generic

Comment: You can also have entries in `/etc/cron.d/`, search that directory for your rsync job. Or maybe you created crontabs for different users?

Comment: I found this I had used and remember seeing it in crontab, but I have removed it from there. But it still runs each month.
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /mnt/terabyte/BACKUPS

Comment: Can you show the output of `crontab -l` and `grep -r media /etc/cron.d/`? Mask every information that's critical before posting it.

Comment: have you check crontab for root and your usual user (you do not work  as root don't you ? ) ?

Comment: No I run non-root, but it wouldn't hurt to check if there is a section it might be in under root.

Here are the requested outputs. 

on@ron-desktop:~$ crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.

ron@ron-desktop:~$ 


ron@ron-desktop:~$ grep -r media /etc/cron.d/
ron@ron-desktop:~$

Comment: Sorry, that didn't format right. But there is nothing in cron
And the grep found nothing

Comment: Instead of posting output as a comment you should edit your question and use the code tags to make it readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll certainly do that from now on. I found how to locate the crontab for root. There it was, right in front of me. Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it.

Thanks @Archemar for the hint that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to check all system & user cron jobs that are calling rsync, grep is your friend:

```
grep -R rsync /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron
```

That will check all crontabs (/etc/crontab & /var/spool/cron/>USERNAMES>),as well as the system locations /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly & /etc/cron.monthly. So if it's done via cron, then that's where you'll find it.

The output will be in the form:

```
/path/to/file/that/includes/match:line_that_matches
```

Once you know where it is, you can then edit/delete/disable the job.

One thing for future readers of this post to be aware of though, is that these days, cron is not the only show in town. Cron is still popular and used heavily, but systemd (the init system used by most distros these days) has "timers". Similar to cron jobs, they provide a facility to auto-run commands on a schedule. Systemd-timers do offer more flexibility than cron, but are also more complex, so more things to go wrong...

Because of the way systemd is organised, a simple grep won't do. There may be a better/easier way, but using grep again, but this time with find should do the trick. Something like this (should output formatted similar to above):

```
for dir in /etc /run /lib; do
    find $dir/systemd -type f -name "*.timer" -exec grep rsync /dev/null {} \;
done
```

(To search for something other than 'rsync' just swap that out for the search term you want to use - if it includes spaces, put it in quotes).